# How can I either through vbscript or GPO push a Windows 7 Logon Screen to all my users

Tags: windows, group-policy, user-management, vbscript

I know how to change the login screen, it's easy. But I would like to figure out a way to do it through GPO or login script. I have tried running the script as the computer start-up script as well as the users login script(GPO) But the users do not have admin rights and the require UAC to replace the backgroundDefault.jpg. Turning UAC off is not an option.

Any idea's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply copy the file to all your machines from an administrator logon. That's more or less what I did. I just did it one at a time, but you could put that in a batch file.

Comment: This is all we did. Make a GPO to do this in the machine context, not a user's context. Job done.

Comment: RobM are talking about running a script via GPO from the Computer side versus the user side? ie the startup vs login script? Cause I tried that and it didn't work for me..

Comment: ETL - that was what I was thinking as well just using a for loop to circulate through the subnet. I just though is was little inelegant, however effective. I was hoping to just automate through GPO. But I think at this point you have a the top answer. Thanks!